# When I take an nth root in Python and NumPy, which of the n existing roots do I actually get?

Tags: python, numpy, math, polynomials

Entailed by the [fundamental theorem of algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra) is the existence of n complex roots for the formula z^n=a where a is a real number, n is a positive integer, and z is a complex number. Some roots will also be real in addition to complex (i.e. a+bi where b=0).

One example where there are multiple real roots is z^2=1 where we obtain z = ±sqrt(1) = ± 1. The solution z = 1 is immediate. The solution z = -1 is obtained by z = sqrt(1) = sqrt(-1 * -1) = I * I = -1, which I is the imaginary unit.

In Python/NumPy (as well as many other programming languages and packages) only a single value is returned. Here are two examples for 5^{1/3}, which has 3 roots.

```py
>>> 5 ** (1 / 3)
1.7099759466766968
```

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.power(5, 1/3)
1.7099759466766968
```

It is not a problem for my use case that only one of the possible roots are returned, but it would be informative to know '**which**' root is systematically calculated in the contexts of Python and NumPy. Perhaps there is an (ISO) standard stating which root should be returned, or perhaps there is a commonly-used algorithm that happens to return a specific root. I've imagined of an equivalence class such as "the maximum of the real-valued solutions", but I do not know.

**Question**: When I take an nth root in Python and NumPy, which of the n existing roots do I actually get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since typically the idenity xᵃ = exp(a⋅log(x)) is used to define the general power, you'll get the root corresponding to the chosen [branch cut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_point#Branch_cuts) of the [complex logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm).

With regards to this, the [numpy documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.log.html) says:

> For real-valued input data types, log always returns real output. For each value that cannot be expressed as a real number or infinity, it yields nan and sets the invalid floating point error flag.

> For complex-valued input, log is a complex analytical function that has a branch cut [-inf, 0] and is continuous from above on it. log handles the floating-point negative zero as an infinitesimal negative number, conforming to the C99 standard.

So for example, `np.power(-1 +0j, 1/3) = 0.5 + 0.866j = np.exp(np.log(-1+0j)/3)`.